# How to Render pdf to file

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, pdf, render

I have an aspx page and i want to render it to a file as pdf.

```
 FileStream fs = File.Create(path);
        converter.SavePdfFromHtmlStringToStream(
            pagehtml, fs);
        fs.Close();
```

I am getting error on this code. My doubt is whether the filestream i am using is in correct format or not?

Comment: Any answer Code Gurus???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the Filestream You are using is correct. the point is check where your calling this code. i have used in render event(page-prerender) and got error.